# How to remove accents in CI active record?

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I faced some problem with CodeIgniter's active record as it automatically adds accents. For example i need to use this `ORDER BY FIELD(`sites`.`ID`, 120, 27, 119)`, so i do it like `$this->db->order_by('FIELD(`sites`.`ID`, '.implode(', ', $sites).' )');`, but getting

```
ORDER BY FIELD(`sites`.`ID`, `120`, `27`, `119`)
```

I also tried to add apostrophes, but nothing has changed. Is there any way to do my query or i need to rewrite it as a simple query?

Answer (score 0):

> $this->db->where() accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.

[Active Record documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)